Laravel Livewire with dockling libraries such as golden-layout
when using Livewire I have not yet found a way to use docking libraries such as Golden-Layout
The main problem is that I cannot move a Livewire component inside the layout or render it dynamically after page load.
One (janky) fix I found was to use teleport but this brings a lot of downsides such as not working within nested components (such as the whole page is a component which uses golden-layout in it)
I have also looked at the DOM hooks provided by the Livewire Javascript API but to no avail.
Does anyone here have a Idea on how to use Livewire with Docking/DOM modifying/moving libraries?
